# Does any body know how to delay a mouse re-click for a specified time delay?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the HTML control below and want a delay after it is clicked so users cannot accidentally or intentionally click it again-

UPDATE SYNCHRONIZED VALUES

```
<a href="Javascript:main.ManualCommand.perform( 'command here' )"><FONT size=3 COLOR = White> UPDATE SYNCHRONIZED VALUES</FONT></A>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `main.ManualCommand.perform` add something like this

```
var lastClick = 0;
var delay = 1000; // 1 second

function perform(command) {
    if (Date.now() < lastClick + delay) {
        // can't click yet
        return;
    }
    lastClick = Date.now(); // set the last click to this moment
    // perform your actual logic here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With JQuery maybe you can try something like this:

```
    var linkClicked = false;

    $("#link").click(function () {

        if (!linkClicked) {

            linkClicked = true;

            setTimeout(function () { linkClicked = false; }, 3000); // Put the time you want to delay in ms

            //Do stuff
        }
    })
```

Remember you have to put the id to the link so that it looks like this:

```
<a href="Javascript:main.ManualCommand.perform( 'command here' )" id="link"><font size=3 color=White> UPDATE SYNCHRONIZED VALUES</font></a>
```

Comment: Sorry guys i am really no good at this stuff, so would anybody be able to fill it out for me with a 60 second delay?

Comment: Right there in the `setTimeout` function replace the **3000** with **60000**. 60000 milli seconds are the same are 60 seconds. Hope it helps!

Comment: Just to clarify, the `setTimeout` configures a function so that it runs once a specified time has passed. So we are telling it that it should reset the `linkClicked` variable when 60 seconds have passed so that the link can be clicked again.

Comment: Im sorry to be a pest about it but i mean where in the above string do i put my html string?? im not sure of the spacing and punctuation required to make it work. In stupid terms can someone write out the entire string for me so that i can just copy and paste it?

Comment: Adam, what HTML are you refering to? Which string are you talking about? The code shown above is all you need to do what you requested. I suggest you to edit your question with the code you have tried.